# CMake 2.8.10.1 treats debug/optimized as a relative directory

Tags: cmake

In my CMakeLists.txt, I have line 33:

```
link_directories (${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

where `${QT_LIBRARIES}` expands to:

```
optimized;C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/msvc2010/lib/QtOpenGL4.lib;debug;C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/msvc2010/lib/QtOpenGLd4.lib
```

After an update to CMake 2.8.10.1, I get the following warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:33 (link_directories):
  This command specifies the relative path

    optimized

  as a link directory.

  Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
  source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

However, as you can see, `${QT_LIBRARIES}` **does not** contain relative path.
In my opinion, CMP0015 policy is not relevant here.

Is it my mistake somewhere or is there a bug in CMake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${QT_LIBRARIES}` is a list of *libraries,* not *library paths.* It's designed to be used in `target_link_libraries()`. Replace your line 33 with:

```
targe_link_libraries(yourTargetName ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that use of `link_directories()` is discouraged in favour of full paths in `target_link_libraries()` anyway.